# sqlalchemy column_property and left joins

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, left-join

I have two models, Student and TestResult that are linked through a one-to-many relationship using the student_id on both tables. One student can have many test results, or (and this is where the problems begin...) can have no test results at all.

I have created a calculated column using @hybrid_property on TestResult to tell me which is the current result, and I have added another column to my Student model to tell me if that particular student has a current test result or not, ie Student.test_taken = True if they have taken a test today.

My problem lies with students that do NOT have a current_result. I have got it working with the code below, but this seems way over complicated for what would be in pure SQL, a super simple problem. I have tried rewriting as a coalesce but I can't get it to work as I expect, and tbh I am not even sure if I am going about this in the right way.

Can someone advise if I am approaching this correctly, and if not, help me find a better solution?

```
class TestResult(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'testresult'

    result_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    student_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('students.studentid'))
    test_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    test_result = db.Column(db.String)

    @hybrid_property
    def current_result(self):
        if self.test_date = datetime.today:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    @current_result.expression
    def current_result(self):
        return case([
            (self.test_date = func.now(), True)
        ], else_ = False)


class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'student'
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String)
    surname = db.Column(db.String)
    class = db.Column(db.String)

    test_taken = column_property(

        select([
            case([(exists().where(and_(
                student_id == TestResult.student_id,
                TestResult.current_result == True,
            )).correlate_except(TestResult), True)],
                 else_=False,
            )
        ])
    )
    test_results = relationship('TestResult', backref='student')
```

Comment: This seems like a case of spurious CASE. In other words why don't you just return `cls.test_date == func.current_date()` in your hybrid prop and just select that in your column prop. Note that you have multiple spots where you've mixed assignment and equality comparison. `datetime.today` is a function, so you should call it, though you shouldn't be calling that at all, but `date.today()`. The former returns a `datetime` object.

Comment: For the purposes of the the example I have simplified the case statement in the hybrid prop. The bit I'm not sure about is the column_property bit on the Student model, is that sensible?